# Python 2.7 Unicode Error within a function (using __future__ print_function and unicode_literals)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I've read some threads about unicode now.

I am using Python 2.7.2  but with the future print_function (because the raw print statement is quite confusing for me..)

So here is some code:

```
# -*- coding: L9 -*-
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
```

now if I print things like

```
print("öäüß§€")
```

it works perfectly.
However, and yes I am totally new to python, if I declare a function which shall print unicode strings it blows my script

```
def foo():
    print("öäüß€")

foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    foo()
  File "C:\Python27\test1.py", line 5, in foo
    print("÷õ³▀Ç")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x80' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>
```

What's the best way to handle this error and unicode in general?
And should I stick with the 2.7 print statement instead?

Comment: Your code does work for me. Personally, I would avoid using print statement

Comment: Thanks alexvassel, do you run it on linux? I'm trying it on xp - should've write it in the question..

Comment: I use Linux and Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `print("öäüß€".encode('L9'))` will solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and the hint.
Well it stops my script from blowing but there's something wrong with the letters. The output looks like this now:
÷õ³▀Ç


edit: now if i change the console codepage to 1252 (western europe), the letters are fine again. However there must be a solution within the standard 850chcp since the first print statement works with special chars

Comment: @AdventureTime For it to work properly in the sense that it looks right in your console, the encoding specified to `encode` has to *both* (a) be capable of handling all unicode characters in the string; *and* (b) be compatible with encoding set for your console. If you don't want to adjust your terminal encoding, then adjust the encoding in your code. In general, though, I recommend that you set all encodings in editor and console to utf-8.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Now what I did is change the coding cookie to # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
and using print("öäüß€".encode("utf-8")) but the console now slaps my face with this error "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte"

Comment: @AdventureTime, you have to save the *source file* in UTF-8.  The coding line declares the source file encoding.  It won't solve the problem, though.  cp850 doesn't support the Euro character.

Comment: sure I did not forget about that. after changing the cp to 1252 I get these letters "Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼â‚¬". but how come echo € works on cp 850?

Comment: Make sure to save in UTF-8 *without BOM*.  I just tried with a UTF-8 BOM in my source and got a syntax error as well.  Python strictly supports the cp850 code page, but Microsoft can alter the rules to support a Euro at the console with echo.  They wrote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Console code pages use legacy "OEM" code pages for compatibility with by old DOS console programs, while the rest of Windows uses updated code pages that support modern characters, but still differ by region.  In your case the console uses `cp850` and GUI programs use `cp1252`.  `cp850` doesn't support the Euro character, so Python raises an exception when trying to print the character on the console.  You can run `chcp 1252` before running your script if you need the Euro to work.  Make sure the console font supports the character, though.

BTW, `L9` != `cp1252` either.

Are you sure printing from the console worked with a Euro?  When I cut-and-paste your `print`, I get the following if the code page is 850, but it works after `chcp 1252`.

```
>>> print("öäüß§€")
öäüß§?                 # Note the ?
```

Encoding charts:

- [cp850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)
- [cp1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)
- [L9 (aka ISO-8859-15)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)

Comment: Thanks for the comment; About the cp: last link says "ISO/IEC 8859-15 are also found in Windows-1252."    however how come this works in my console?: C:\Python27\test1>chcp
Aktive Codepage: 850.

C:\Python27\test1>echo €€€
€€€

Comment: `echo` works for me too, but Python `print` doesn't.  `echo` is not Python and I suspect Microsoft is playing games behind the scenes so Europeans are happy in the console.  The console can display characters that aren't in its code chart.  I can type a Euro, but Python won't print one.  Refer to the chart links.  Not all of 8859-15 is in Windows 1252.

Comment: okay thank you, the whole topic seems to me inconsistent. for example I run the script, it prints some letters. I reboot my machine and run it again with the same settings it shows me totally different letters.. somehow frustrating

Comment: Okay, is there a way to force the chcp through python?

Comment: thats great, thank you. is there also a way of hiding the print of 'active codepage: 1252' ?   what came in my mind first was os.system('echo off') but it doesn't work.

Comment: `os.system('chcp 1252 >nul')` perhaps.

Comment: thanks, yes this works :) in the meanwhile I found a second solution: `subprocess.check_output("chcp 1252", shell = True)`

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
print(type(s1))
s1.encode('ascii',errors='ignore') #this works
s1.decode('ascii',errors='ignore') #this does not work
```

The reason is that s1.decode can't decode unicode directly so an explicit call to encode is first made, but without the errors='ignore' flag thus an error is raised

Depending on whether you were issuing your commands from a file or from a python prompt with unicode support may explain why you get an error in the latter but not the former.